# Dynamic X-Axis Date Range Based on Disconnected Slicer

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have an issue that I need a hand with. I am using a disconnected slicer based off of this table

```
Time Frame := 
DATATABLE("ID", Integer, "Time Frame", string
, {
  {1, "3 Month"}
, {2, "6 Month"}
, {3, "9 Month"}
, {4, "12 Month"}
})
```

that looks like this:

[image]

Using a few DAX measures:

```
Sum Of Paid := sum(Data[Paid])

Sum Of Paid 3 Month Period :=
CALCULATE (
    [Sum Of Paid],
    DATESINPERIOD ( Data[Date], LASTDATE ( Data[Date] ), -3, MONTH )
)

Sum Of Paid 6 Month Period :=
CALCULATE (
    [Sum Of Paid],
    DATESINPERIOD ( Data[Date], LASTDATE ( Data[Date] ), -6, MONTH )
)

Sum Of Paid 9 Month Period :=
CALCULATE (
    [Sum Of Paid],
    DATESINPERIOD ( Data[Date], LASTDATE ( Data[Date] ), -9, MONTH )
)

Sum Of Paid 12 Month Period :=
CALCULATE (
    [Sum Of Paid],
    DATESINPERIOD ( Data[Date], LASTDATE ( Data[Date] ), -12, MONTH )
)

Slicer - Paid Per Period :=
VAR selection =
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( 'Time Frame'[Time Frame] ),
        VALUES ( 'Time Frame'[Time Frame] ),
        "All"
    )
VAR ThreeMonth = [Sum of Paid 3 Month Period]
VAR SixMonth = [Sum of Paid 6 Month Period]
VAR NineMonth = [Sum of Paid 9 Month Period]
VAR TwelveMonth = [Sum of Paid 12 Month Period]
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        selection = "3 Month", ThreeMonth,
        selection = "6 Month", SixMonth,
        selection = "9 Month", NineMonth,
        selection = "12 Month", TwelveMonth,
        TwelveMonth
    )
```

I can simulate a slicer and display 3, 6, 9 and 12 month aggregates depending on the users selection. These work just fine in cards, choropleths and almost everything I've needed them for. My issue is trying to create line graphs, bar charts, etc that have a date range on the x-axis. I can't for the life of me figure out how to replicate the period referenced in the DAX measure to dynamically set the x-axis.

I've tried a few approaches that seem like they should work but do not:

```
3 Month Period :=
CALCULATE (
    VALUES(Data[Date]),
    DATESINPERIOD ( Data[Date], LASTDATE ( Data[Date] ), -3, MONTH )
)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try this one:

```
3 Month Period :=
CALCULATE (
    [Sum Of Paid],
    KEEPFILTERS (
        DATESINPERIOD (
            Data[Date],
            CALCULATE (
                MAX ( Data[Date] ),
                ALLSELECTED ()
            ),
            -3,
            MONTH
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know you used Stack Overflow! I hope you stick around as interest in DAX has been picking up and there are not too many experts to help answer questions.

Comment: I am honored Marco, thanks for taking the time to help me out. Unfortunately when I use this measure I get a semantic error, specifically: "The CalculateTable function expects a table expression for argument 1 but a string or numeric expression was used." I did try playing around with a bit but my changes yield a Calculation Error: "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected"

Comment: And that is why you are the KING! Grazie mille!!